# Using position: fixed with display: flex

Tags: html, css, css-position, navbar

I gave my navbar the property of `display: flex;` and I also want the navbar to be fixed. Why `position: fixed;` doesn't work but `position: sticky;` is working for the same?

As soon as I added the property of `position: fixed;`, my navbar squeezed.

Comment: Would be more helpful if you could post pictures of how the navbar looks under the different properties.

Answer (score 1):

When using **display: flex;** on a navbar, **position: fixed;** alone may not work as expected because it removes the element from the normal document flow and makes it fixed relative to the viewport. This can lead to unintended consequences on the sizing of the flex container.

**position: sticky;** is working for you because it blends both behaviors. It acts as **position: relative;** within its parent container until it reaches a certain scroll position, at which point it becomes **position: fixed;** and sticks to the viewport. This allows the navbar to participate in the flex layout while also being fixed when needed.

If you want to use **position: fixed;** with flex, make sure that the fixed element is a child of a flex container, and you might need to explicitly set the width to prevent squeezing.

```
/* Parent container with flex */
.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Fixed navbar */
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Set width to prevent squeezing */
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* Add other styling properties as needed */
}
```

Remember to adjust the styling according to your specific layout and design requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `width: 100%` to your element

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: skyblue;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  
  width: 100%; /* try changing this line */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```